# DBA_SCHEDULER_RUNNING_JOBS missing in schema

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, database-administration

So there is a certain plsql code am doing and I have to refer the DBA_SCHEDULER_RUNNING_JOBS, for it to work. We recently cleared out everything from the schema am using and then used the dump to re-import the schema. The code used to work before  but now when ever I refer to DBA_SCHEDULER_RUNNING_JOBS the compilation fails with the error 'table or view does not exist.' Has anyone ever encountered something like this? Can someone shed some light on this and help me or suggest a fix...

Comment: How you exported the schema, using normal `export` or using `datapump`?

Comment: i used expdb for exporting the schema..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, GRANT was not given on the table after the schema was exported, that explains why the code was running before and now giving problems...